# Unable to correctly install MS Speech Platform 11 on Win 7 x64

Tags: speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform

so I'm trying to get up and running MS Speech Platform 11 + SDK + Russian Language for TTS and SR

1. Installing SpeechPlatformRuntime.x64.msi
2. Installing MicrosoftSpeechPlatformSDK.x64.msi
   --- Both goes to correct "Program Files" folder.
3. Installing MSSpeech_SR_ru-RU_TELE.msi
4. Installing MSSpeech_TTS_ru-RU_Elena.msi
   --- Both goes to "Program Files (x86)" folder. - is it OK?

Seems like no, because when I look at SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers() it returns 2 items:

```
MS-1033-80-DESK
Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - US)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Recognizers\Tokens\MS-1033-80-DESK

MS-2057-80-DESK
Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - UK)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Speech\\Recognizers\\Tokens\\MS-2057-80-DESK
```

But I have never installed this recognizers. I've looked into Win 7 component and can't find any related to this.

So questions are:

1. Is it required to install languages in x64 Program Files? If so, how to do that?
2. How to configure recognizer and synthesizer to see ru-RU languages?

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got it. I don't know why it is so complex. May be I'm doing something wrong. Anyway, it works and located in correct places. So, here is my solution:

1. Install [x64_SpeechPlatformRuntime\SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225)
2. Install [x64\MicrosoftSpeechPlatformSDK.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14373)
3. Using Orca (installation instructions [here](http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/downloading-installing-and-using-ms-orca)) modify `MSSpeech_SR_ru-RU_TELE.msi`, and other languages that you would like to install:

   1. Go to `View` -> `Summary Information`, and set `Platform: x64`.
   2. Go to `Directory` table, and change all occurrences:

      > CommonFilesFolder -> CommonFiles64Folder
      >
      > Common -> CommonFiles64Folder
4. Install selected languages.
5. Place file `Microsoft.Speech.dll` into you project's "Externals" folder and reference this dll from there. (I can't find way how to reference this DLL from VS without this trick).

Comment: What do you mean by "the project's Externals folder"? What folder is that?

Comment: @Pascal I assume he means like a custom `lib` folder within the solution. But I don't know why he'd do this and not just reference `System.Speech`. Anyways, I couldn't get step 3.2 to work, I still get an aborted installation...

Answer (score 2):

I found a very good way to fix those "Runtime Languages" (Version 11).

I'm using Windows 7 64bit and when I first tried to install those Speech Languages, they were not listed in the system. So I searched for a solution...

I found a french web site explaining that we need to modify some registry keys. This method is working but it's very long to do and it leaves a lot of unused Keys in your Registry...

So, why not just fix the bug at it's source? The MSI Installer file!

**Needed Tools:**

To do this, you will need an **MSI Editor**. I'm using "**InstEd 1.5**" which seems to be perfect for what we need to do... and it's free!

You can download it at: [www.instedit.com](http://www.instedit.com)

**Steps:**

For this example, I will fix this file: "**MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_Helen.msi**"
It's the same procedure for any other "Runtime Languages".

1. First, **Uninstall** every "Not Working" Runtime Languages.
2. Open the **MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_Helen.msi** with **"InstEd 1.5"**
3. Select the "**Tables**" Tab.
4. Click on the table named: "**Registry**"
5. You will see a list of **Registry Keys**. It should look like that:

"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech Server\v11.0\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_en-US_Helen_11.0"
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech Server\v11.0\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_en-US_Helen_11.0\Attributes"

6. **Select all** the Rows (**Ctrl+A**)
7. **Right click** on the the selection then **"Cut Rows"** (or use  **Ctrl+Shift+X**)
8. Open your favorite **Text Editor** and **Paste** inside it.
9. With your Text Editor, you need to replace every string of **"Speech Server\v11.0"** by **"Speech"** (use **Ctrl+H** and "**Replace All**")
10. In your Text Editor: **Select all** (**Ctrl+A**) and **Copy** (**Ctrl+C**)
11. Go back to **"InstEd 1.5"**
12. **Right Click** in the "Registry Window" then **"Paste Rows"**
13. **Save** your Fixed MSI file!
14. **Install** your Fixed MSI File!

Comment: Works amazingly on Windows 7! But when I tried this on Windows 8.1 and 10, both HunYee (zh-HK voice) and HanHan (zh-TW voice) failed to start, neither from a script nor from the control panel. Do you happen to know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I combined answers hkurabko and Frank Einstein.

So, more useful Orca, it can replace values in column Keys for each row at once: click Edit -> Replace, type necessary - replace all.

And if you don't want add "Externals" dll, you need install BOTH version of SpeechPlatformRuntime: x64 and x86.

It work for me at Windows 10 1703 (Creators Update).